# question about loop and break command

Tags: java

i have tested following code which  might print  0 and 2 but it print 1 and 1 why?

```
public class break_command {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for (int j=1;j<10;i++){
                if ((i+j) %2==0){
                    System.out.println("i  "+ i +"  j   " +j);
                    break;
                }


            }
            break;
       }
    }

}

result//
i  1  j   1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Note also that the convention in Java is that classes are named in upper camel case, so your class would conventionally be called `BreakCommand`.  While you *can* use any names you like, your code will actually be easier for others to understand if you stick to the conventions.

Comment: @Andrzej Personally, I use two ide's when I develop. I use Eclipse for real development, and I use JGrasp (super light-weight) for testing some tiny little thing. Half the time I end up with `public class foo` or `class bob`. This is the kind of thing I would use that for. It's not like he's creating `BreakCommand` objects or anything.

Comment: @davit I'd recommend stepping through this with a debugger and watching the variables change step by step. When they don't change the way you think they should, the line you're on will jump out at you why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the line:

```
for (int j=1;j<10;i++){
```

Supposed to be j++ not i++?

Otherwise it means on the first iteration:

```
if ((i+j) %2==0){
```

Will be true.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating i inside your second loop, not j.  So initially, in the first loop, i has the value 0.  Then as you enter the second loop, it is increased to 1.  At this point i has the value 1 and j has the value one; their sum is even, so it prints them out and breaks out of the inner loop, breaks out of the outer loop, and you are done.